# segmentation fault when running MATLAB in glnx86 64bit

Tags: linux, matlab, 64-bit

I got a problem when starting Matlab 2011b on ubuntu platform running a server with Intel Xeon processor.

I installed this version of matlab with network lincese, and installation process was quite well done.(I hope so, but there is no extra warning).

When I start matlab with binary in 
  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86 name MATLAB

program dump a core-dump and received SIGSEGV.

I got a backtrace using gdb as follow.

> ```
> #0  0xb7feb2b6 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
> #1  0xb7ff0dba in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
> #2  0xb7feccbf in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
> #3  0xb7ff07e4 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
> #4  0xb70e6be9 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
> #5  0xb7feccbf in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
> #6  0xb70e733a in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2        
> #7  0xb70e6c97 in dlopen () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
> #8  0xb7f330e6 in utLoadLibrary () from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86/libut.so
> #9  0xb2b2a1bc in ?? () from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86/libmwbinder.so
> #10 0xb2b2a412 in Binder::_load_libs(std::vector<std::string,        
> std::allocator<std::string> > const&)
> () from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86/libmwbinder.so
> #11 0xb2b2bd48 in Binder::_load_and_resolve() ()
> from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86/libmwbinder.so
> #12 0xb2abf356 in ?? () from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86/libmwblas.so
> #13 0xb2abf484 in ?? () from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86/libmwblas.so
> #14 0xb2abfd5d in zdotu_ () from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86/libmwblas.so
> #15 0xb2ac23d0 in ?? () from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86/libmwblas.so
> #16 0xb2ab82d8 in _init () from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnx86/libmwblas.so
> #17 0xb7fece39 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
> #18 0xb7fecf84 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
> #19 0xb7fdf20f in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
> =========================================================
> ```

Any comment? or help?

Any word with your attention will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you contacted Matlab's tech support ?  They're usually quite helpful.

Comment: @Ansari can you explain some more details about why I should re-install BLAS?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't start MATLAB directly from your architecture-specific directory.  Try running `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/matlab` instead.The script performs some initializations and is platform-aware. The initialization process is needed because MATLAB uses quite specific (older) versions of some libraries.

If your problem persists, though, I'd contact customer service of The Mathworks.

Comment: It was a problem in license server, not in matlab. Thx anyway!